# Bash Script to export first columns in txt file to excel with Header

Tags: excel, bash, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I would like to export first column of my txt file into excel along with the user defined header

Currently my txt file has following information

```
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
9020 9020
```

and i would like to export it to excel with my own header, how could i possibly do it in bash script?.

Comment: You might look into using csvkit: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for` loop with `sed` maybe this will help:

```
for file in /path/to/folder/*.txt ; do
 bname=$(basename $file)
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 sed -i '1iCOL1,COL2' $file
 done
```

This will add a header `COL1,COL2` to each `.txt` file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
awk -v header="Col_1" 'NR==1 {print header} {print $1}' file
```

That is assuming that the separator between columns is a space and the fields do not have spaces.